# How do I develop an app for a specific build of AOSP from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

My current phone (Pixel 2 XL) is running the build PQ1A.181105.017.A1. According to [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers), that means it was build from branch android-9.0.0_r16. Looking at a source file from that particular branch, for example [SignalStrength.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-9.0.0_r16/telephony/java/android/telephony/SignalStrength.java), there is a public method called getWcdmaRscp(). However, it appears this method was added after SDK version 28 was released, so if I try to call it from my app in Android Studio when targeting 28, it doesn't build.

I'm guessing my phone will gladly allow me to call the method in question, so how do I setup my Android Studio to be able to build against that version of the framework?

It appears I would need a new framework.jar, but where can I find that? Please don't tell me I need to download and build the entire AOSP thing locally.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it was added after API 28 was released. It's annotated with `@hide` which means, when the SDK was built, it wasn't built in. It's still in the framework itself, but Android Studio doesn't know that.

To get around this, you'll have to use reflection. Something like:

```
try {
    Method getWcdmaRscp = SignalStrength.class.getMethod("getWcdmaRscp");
    int rscp = Integer.parseInt(getWcdmaRscp.invoke(signalStrength).toString()); //signalStrength is the instance you have
} catch (Exception ignored) {}
```

However, that probably won't work. Android Pie introduced restrictions on accessing hidden methods and classes. In Oreo, you could just use reflection. In Pie, most of the classes you try to access will throw a `ClassNotFound` or `NoSuchMethodError` exception, because the system prevents third-party apps from accessing them. Certain hidden APIs are still accessible, but there's no definitive list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid you were right in that it is blocked in Pie. I get a NoSuchMethodError exception when trying to call it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the whole framework.jar

While one way would be to use reflection as TheWanderer suggested, another option is to add the single source file you linked to, SignlaStrength.java, to your project.

You just need to make sure you add it under the original package path /android/telephony

The studio will use it for compilation to resolve method signatures, but when running on the phone the calls will go through to the original framework class.
I didn't see any non public imports in the file, but if it does not compile, you may need to turn it in to a stub, by removing some function internals.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I've added the SignalStrength.java class in the correct package path locally. I then had to stub out a couple of things in the class to get it to compile, but the problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get Android Studio to use the local file over the one from the SDK. Do I need to do anything else? Any changes to the gradle files for example?

Comment: What error are you getting?
I used this method with some internal Android classes before and it did not require any changes to gradle.

Comment: Well, basically `Cannot resolve method 'getWcdmaRscp()'`. It appears as if it is still referencing the SDK class rather than my local version.

Having said that, will this work regardless? I tried using reflection and was shut down.

Comment: @RickardAndersson no, it won't work. And this isn't how stubs work, either. If the class is found in the APK itself, the ClassLoader will prefer that over the one in the SDK. But either way, the SDK will still throw a NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.